# How to create and show views on command request?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I've started using mvvm-light toolkit , and new to WPF.

My question is:
I want to create an pplication where the main window includes a grid with 2 columns 1 col command and col2 will display views when each command will be pressed.
i want the views to be created on command and colsed from it's own view.

I've tried to figure out how to do it but with no success.

I don't know how to write this kind of funconality using the mvvm light.

I just know how to create main window with mainview and another view creted already on load.

Please help me out..

I'm using 2008 WPF3.5

Shirly.
Make me happy today.. i've just started the week!!!

ThankU. I have done it and get as a result the Tostring() of the current ViewModel "LU.ViewModel.AllChannelsViewModel" and not the real view.

the View i want to load is :
I'm using the mvvm-light

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8,4,0,0" Name="closebutton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}">Close</Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,4,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Command="{Binding GetChannelsCommand}">Load Channels</Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8,4,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Command="{Binding NewChannelCommand}">New Channel</Button>
    <dg:DataGrid   Grid.Row="2"  ItemsSource="{Binding AllChannelsData}" Margin="0,30,0,0" />


</Grid>
```

What do i miss here? How can i show the real view i want and not the name of the viewmodel?

Shirly

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is anything specific to do that with MVVM Light, but a common way to create a view in MVVM is to create a `ContentControl` that is bound to a property of the ViewModel. When you affect a new ViewModel to that property, the `ContentControl` renders it using the `DataTemplate` that matches the ViewModel's type :

```
<!-- In resources -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FooViewModel}">
    <v:FooView />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BarViewModel}">
    <v:BarView />
</DataTemplate>
...

<!-- In the main view -->

<ContentControl Content="{Binding Current}" />
```

Comment: I think this person meant in creating a view that one would open via a command.

Comment: @Brian, you *think*, but you don't *know*, and the OP never came back to prove you wrong or right, so I don't think it deserves a downvote...

Comment: Thomas, thank you for your response. When I used the word think it was to be polite and not to be a know it all. The text that they wrote specifically states: "...to display views when each command is pressed. I want the views to be created on command...." The very nature of that suggests they want to click a button that's tied to a command that opens a view. Likewise, their xaml contains two buttons which suggests they understand how to create a view. So, I stand by my down vote. I'm sorry if it offends you.

Comment: @Brian, I'm not offended, I just don't think this answer deserves it... My answer still works in this scenario: for example, if a ContentControl is bound to a property, a command can change that property, which will display a different view in the ContentControl. I use this approach all the time...

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me for giving you an option that is not in MVVM Light toolkit but I have already been down the road that you're on and chose to use Prism for this very reason. I don't have time to go into the details of Prism or event aggregators but in that tool you would:

1. In your view model create an ICommand that you'd bind your button or events to
2. Your executed command would call an event aggregator with the method publish. This is an event that you have already set up outside of your VM and is waiting to be called. When called, the event shows your form. You can even pass properties or even other VM's to the event. This allows your VM not to know about the View.

Finally, MVVM has been wonderful for me but it will offer you many challenges such as this. Don't expect to conquer it in one day or create applications quickly but when you get everything in order it is a nice paradigm.